# No route matches [GET] "/users/1/categories/5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to query data for all the **items** a **user** has liked from a specific **category**. EG: */users/1/categories/5*

I'm having a bit of a Rails-101 issue and can't find out why the server is telling me the route doesn't exist.

The params are correct. The route exists in Routes.rb. The only thing I can think of is the order in which the routes appear. Or perhaps something due to the SPA nature of the routing.

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  ACCEPTS_JSON = lambda {|request|
    request.accepts.include?(:json)
  }

  get "/users/email" => "users#id"
  get "/items/:id/like" => "items#checkhasliked"
  get "/users/:u_id/categories/:c_id " => "users#categoryitems" // should do the trick?

  scope constraints: ACCEPTS_JSON do
    resources :users
    resources :categories
    resources :items
  end

  get "/*path" => "app#main"

  post "/users" => "users#create"
  post "/items" => "items#create"

  post "/items/:id/like" => "items#like"

  post "/items/:id/unlike" => "items#unlike"

  post "/sessions" => "sessions#create"

  root 'app#main'
end
```

UsersController:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

        ...

        def categoryitems
            render json: {head: :ok}
        end
    end
```

The ajax call:

```
fetchCategoryItems: function(cID){
    var uID = this.props.params.id   // user ID
    var cID = cID   // category ID 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/users/" + uID + "/categories/" + cID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            this.setState({didFetchData: 'true', items: data.items})
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(data){
            alert("error! couldn't fetch user's items-by-category")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this instead in your routes file

```
  resources :users, only: [:show] do
     resources :categories, only: [:show], to:  'users#categoryitems'
  end
```